# How does System.String save its string

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages, language-implementation

To become better at .NET I found it helpful to look into the .Net-Framework itself and how Microsoft implements all the nice things. The last time I used my decompiler to have a look at the implementation of `System.String-Class`, to research how a String-Object stores its actual string. I was surprised about the largest of the class in self and that I can't clearly identify which part of the class the actual string saves.

Here are two screenshot of the decompiling which shows the start and the end part of the class:
[image]
[image]

I suppose that `[System.Reflection.DefaultMember("Chars")]` (first line in first screenshot) and/or the property `public extern char this[int index]`(middle of second screenshot) the what I am looking for.

Is that the correct and if yes how does it work?

Comment: Would be helpful for further questions if upvoter and downvoter leave a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.String` is a *very* special type. It's the only type in .NET other than arrays where different instances can have different sizes. (Anything else which "appears" to have different sizes such as `List<T>` usually depends on an array, or some recursive type like a `LinkedList` node. The objects themselves are of a fixed size.) The character data is inline within the object itself, along with the length of the string. It's not like a `String` holds a reference to a `char[]` or similar.

The CLR has very deep knowledge of `System.String`, and a lot of it is implemented in native code. Basically, I would recommend *against* trying to understand the implementation at this point - it's likely to be more confusing than helpful.

The `Chars` member (the indexer in C#) only *fetches* a single character from the string. You could follow that to find out more about where the data is stored, but it doesn't perform the actual storage itself.

Comment: Allthough I agree this sounds more like a comment than an answer to me

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: I've added a bit more concrete information about where the actual data lives.

Comment: I guess will be good to add also link to the chapter of Jon's book "C# in Depth": [Strings in C# and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

Comment: Thank Jon for your answer. A little bit surprising (but very interesting) that the things are so complex.